# Why does the request function of my AngularJS HTTP interceptor get called so many times?

Tags: angularjs

I have an AngularJS HTTP interceptor:

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push([
    "$rootScope", "$q", "$location",
    function ($rootScope, $q, $location) {

        return {
            'request': function (config) {
                var loc = $location.path();
                console.log("path: " + loc);
                ....
                ....
                return config;
            },
            ...
            };
        }
    ]);
```

I make a call that returns an array of 25 items.  The items are populated into the html using ng-repeat.  This display results in 75 calls to the request function.

Can anybody explain why it makes so many calls for one HTTP request?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The http interceptor gets called for **every** request angular does, not just data requests. So also template requests, this might explain why it's so high.

---

Update: to filter out the templates I always use the following function.

```
function isLocalUrl(url) {
    return !(url.indexOf('http://') === 0 || url.indexOf('https://') === 0);
}
```

and call it like this:

```
return {
    'request': function (config) {
        if(isLocalUrl(config.url))
            return config;
    }
}
```

Comment: That would explain it; is there any established pattern for working around this, and limiting the checks to just the data request?